# Stretching my menu div 100% vertically

Tags: html

I've wasted numerous hours on this and cannot seem to get it to work, I've read many answers on here already but none seem to be helping.

I have a header DIV then then two DIV's underneath floated Left of eachother. the menu on the left and content on the right. the right i have set Overflow: hidden so it sits next to the menu div on left and against broswer on right.

Now i want the menu Div on the left to fill the height downwards to match the content div on the right but i cannot for the life of me seem to get the settings right.

The link to website is here http://www.mxbempire.com

Anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

im not 100% sure what you are asking.

however using static attributes on your header and menu would give it a 'wiki-feel'

adding this to your CSS will give an example

```
.menu{position:fixed; top:80px}
.headercontainer{position:fixed; top: 20px;}
.user{padding-left: 200px; float:none;}
.card{margin: 90px 25px 0 250px;}
```

Comment: I would like the site to scroll as it does normally, but i want to make the menu bg color stretch to the bottom of the page, essentially were i will have the footer div, but i cannot get the menu div to stretch vertically 100%, or to match the content div next to it. Hope that makes a bit more sense.

Comment: either making it position:fixed; or giving a height equal to the entirety of your page should do this. ensuring you remove all margins, padding and borders

Comment: The only problem is the page height changes depending on the content, perhaps jquery to find the height of the content div?

Comment: I appreciated the time you have taken to reply! Thanks

Comment: AH, i understand, try this:

  body{background: #373c48;}

  .three {background: white;}

Comment: ^^ Thanks i did think about this at one point but never chased it, this does seem like the easiest way to accomplish this! works a treat.

Thanks again for your help, this place has been such a great help for me!

Answer (score 0):

use this in your css

```
.headercontainer {
width: 100%;
height: 60px;
margin: 0 auto;
background-color: #2C2E33;
position: fixed;
top: 0;

.two {
float: left;
width: 220px;
position: fixed;
top: 60px;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work yes, but changes the way i want to make the site work. perhaps this is an option yes, i appreciate the response!

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this styles to your css:

```
.headercontainer {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
}
.menu {
    height: 100vh;
    margin-top: 60px;
    position: fixed;
}
.three {
    margin-left: 220px;
    padding-top: 60px;
}
```

I'm not sure how it will behave on older browsers, soo just try it.